# I need help highlighting cells with repeated text between 2 columns in google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make a google spreadsheet that I can actively type names into, and when I then type those same names into the adjacent column, they grey out the same name in the previous column, while keeping the ones that don't repeat un-highlighted. I want to be able to type them in any order and still have it work. Right now, it sort of works, however, it only greys out the previous names if the new names in the right column are in a lower row than the ones in the left. This may not make sense, so look at the attached image. The code on the top of the screenshot is what I have entered into the conditional format rules, see 2nd screenshot. I'm quite new to google sheet equations and I've been trying to figure this out for awhile. Anybody know how to accomplish this? Thank You.[image: What the code is currently doing, equation used in the top text bar][image: The conditional format rules imputed, with aforementioned equation]

Answer (score 1):

To solve your issue, I will first create a helper sheet (you can do it within same sheet also) for a result used as a reference:

```
=arrayformula(IF(Sheet16!B2:B=Sheet16!C2:C,True,False))
```

Return `True` if the column value is equal to adjacent column

[image]

On your main sheet, I will enter the custom formula for conditional formatting and apply to the range you need:

```
=indirect("Helper!C2:C")=TRUE
```

Here is the final result, does it help?

[image]

Comment: That didn't seem to do it. Thank you for the help, but your proposed equations only work if the text is the same across the 2 columns in the same row. What I'm looking for is that in the second column, the text can be in any row and still grey it out from the first row. For example, in the first column, if "a" was in row 1, and "b" was in row 2, I should be able to type "a" in either row and it will still be greyed out in the first column. I don't know if I'm explaining it well, but is there a way this can be done? Thank you.

Comment: Ya, the first answer seem get the result you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the column you need to grey out:

`=AND(A1 <> ""; MATCH(A1; B:B;))`

[image]

If you apply it to `B19:B33` and want to look only in `C13:C33` it will look like this:

`=AND(B13 <> ""; MATCH(B13; C$13:C$33;))`